# Sublime Text 2 side bar SVN status

Tags: tortoisesvn, sublimetext2

I am new to the Sublime Text 2 IDE.

I have installed the TortoiseSVN package, but was wondering if there is a way to show a file's status (needing commit/up-to-date) in the file list?

I used to get that with eclipse and e-texteditor.

Have looked literally everywhere for it!

Thanks in advance.
James

Comment: Not requested result, but nearest iteration: [Sublime Tortoise](http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/tortoise) with "Status" command for  Working Copy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the sidebar you can't get the file status like eclipse. You have to run command to check the status . Then it will show the status in a text file